# Sending piped commands via python3 subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipe, subprocess

I am trying to execute the following subprocess command via python3.4

```
cd /home/mailer-domains/domain | rndc loadkeys domain
```

I have tried numerous methods using .call and .Popen but it either doesn't like my pipe or it doesn't like my switch

```
>>> subprocess.call(['cd /home/mailer-domains/'+domain, '|', 'rndc', 'loadkeys', domain])    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 537, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1457, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cd /home/mailer-domains/lecomm.com'

>>> subprocess.call(['cd /home/ex-mailer-domains/'+domain, '&&', 'rndc', 'loadkeys', domain]) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 537, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1457, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cd /home/mailer-domains/lecomm.com'


>>> subprocess.call(['cd', '/home/mailer-domains/'+domain, '&&', 'rndc', 'loadkeys', domain])
cd: too many arguments
2


>>> subprocess.Popen(['cd', '/home/mailer-domains/'+domain, '&&', 'rndc', 'loadkeys', domain])    
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x805aa5860>
cd: too many arguments


>>> subprocess.call(['cd', '/home/mailer-domains/'+domain] '&&' ['rndc', 'loadkeys', domain])    
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    subprocess.call(['cd', '/home/mailer-domains/'+domain] '&&' ['rndc', 'loadkeys', domain])
                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


>>> subprocess.call(['cd', '/home/mailer-domains/'+domain], '&&' ['rndc', 'loadkeys', domain])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers


>>> subprocess.call(['cd', '/home/mailer-domains/'+domain], ['rndc', 'loadkeys', domain])     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 537, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 767, in __init__
    raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer


>>> subprocess.call(['cd', '/home/mailer-domains/'+domain] ['rndc', 'loadkeys', domain])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple


>>> subprocess.call(['cd', '/home/mailer-domains/'+domain] +['rndc', 'loadkeys', domain])
cd: too many arguments
2


>>> ps = subprocess.Popen((['cd', '/home/mailer-domains/'+domain]), stdout = subprocess.PIPE)        
>>> output = subprocess.check_output((['rndc', 'loadkeys', domain]), stdin=ps.stdout)
rndc: 'loadkeys' failed: not found
no matching zone 'lecomm.com' in any view
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 620, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['rndc', 'loadkeys', 'lecomm.com']' returned non-zero exit status 1


>>> output = subprocess.check_output((['rndc', 'loadkeys', domain]), stdin=ps.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'PIPE' is not defined
```

How do I properly send 2 piped commands via Python3 `subprocess`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by piping the output of `cd` (which is normally empty) into the `rndc` process? Do you really just want to run `rndc` in the new directory?

Comment: @TomDalton  I am assuming the loadkey switch looks in the current directory.  I saw some odd behavior that indicated this. I have numerous zone directories each with their own keys.

Comment: though, I am pondering to myself, that sounds silly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer can be found in the [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline).

The functions from the `subprocess` module normally do not call a shell to interpret the commands, but rather invoke them directly with the given arguments! This behaviour can be overidden by using the argument `shell=True` (example from the Python documentation):

```
output = check_output("dmesg | grep hda", shell=True)
```

However, this is not advisable if the command and arguments are not fix but depends on user input. Then, the correct way to do this is to use two `Popen` calls and construct the pipeline by hand (code example again from the Python documentation):

```
p1 = Popen(["dmesg"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "hda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: There is no need for a pipe at all. the cwd can be passed to subprocess

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Agreed in this case. However, someone searching for the title of this question will almost certainly be interested in this answer.

Comment: There are 1000 dupes of how to pipe, this is not the approach to take for the OP, piping when you can pass the directory makes no sense

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: 1001... :D

Comment: Well it sure helped me out! Thanks @Sebastian Riese

Answer (score 5):

You don't need pipes at all, just pass the `cwd` to to subprocess:

```
subprocess.call(['rndc', 'loadkeys', domain],cwd='/home/mailer-domains/'+domain)
```

If you did wanted to  change directory for more than just the subprocess, you should use `os.chdir`.