# Sending multiple piped commands via subprocess with explicit quotations

Tags: python-3.x, shell, subprocess, pipe, popen

I have been trying to execute piped commands via the `subprocess` module, but am having some issues.

I have seen the solutions proposed below, but none have solved my problem:
- [sending a sequence (list) of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683779/subprocess-popen-how-to-pass-a-list-as-argument)
- [several `Popen` commands using `subprocess.PIPE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655841/python-subprocess-how-to-use-pipes-thrice?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [sending a string with `shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257856/sending-piped-commands-via-python3-subprocess)

**I would like to avoid the third option, with `shell=True`, although it did produce the expected results on my test system.**

Here is the command that works in Terminal, which I would like to replicate:

```
tr -c "[:alpha:]" " " < some\ file\ name_raw.txt | sed -E "s/ +/ /g" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" > clean_in_one_command.txt
```

This command cleans files as required. It first uses the `tr` command on an input file, which has spaces in the name. The output is passed to `sed`, which removes some whitespace and then passes the contents to `tr` again to make everything lower case.

After several iterations, I ended up breaking it all down into the simplest form I could, implementing the second method above: several instances of `Popen`, passing information using `subprocess.PIPE`. It is long-winded, but will hopefully make debugging easier:

```
from subprocess import run, Popen, PIPE

cmd1_func = ['tr']
cmd1_flags = ['-c']
cmd1_arg1 = [r'"[:alpha:]\"']
cmd1_arg2 = [r'" "']
cmd1_pass_input = ['<']
cmd1_infile = ['some file name_raw.txt']
cmd1 = cmd1_func + cmd1_flags + cmd1_arg1 + cmd1_arg2 + cmd1_pass_input + cmd1_infile
print("Command 1:", cmd1)    # just to see if things look fine

cmd2_func = ['sed']
cmd2_flags = ['-E']
cmd2_arg = [r'"s/ +/ /g\"']
cmd2 = cmd2_func + cmd2_flags + cmd2_arg
print("command 2:", cmd2)

cmd3_func = ['tr']
cmd3_arg1 = ["\"[:upper:]\""]
cmd3_arg2 = ["\"[:lower:]\""]
cmd3_pass_output = ['>']
cmd3_outfile = [output_file_abs]
cmd3 = cmd3_func + cmd3_arg1 + cmd3_arg2 + cmd3_pass_output + cmd3_outfile
print("command 3:", cmd3)

# run first command into first process
proc1, _ = Popen(cmd1, stdout=PIPE)
# pass its output as input to second process
proc2, _ = Popen(cmd2, stdin=proc1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
# close first process
proc1.stdout.close()
# output of second process into third process
proc3, _ = Popen(cmd3, stdin=proc2.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
# close second process output
proc2.stdout.close()
# save any output from final process to a logger
output = proc3.communicate()[0]
```

I would then simply write the output to a text file, but the program doesn't get that far, because I receive the following error:

```
usage: tr [-Ccsu] string1 string2
       tr [-Ccu] -d string1
       tr [-Ccu] -s string1
       tr [-Ccu] -ds string1 string2
sed: 1: ""s/ +/ /g\"": invalid command code "
usage: tr [-Ccsu] string1 string2
       tr [-Ccu] -d string1
       tr [-Ccu] -s string1
       tr [-Ccu] -ds string1 string2
```

this suggests that my arguments are not being passed correctly. It seems the `'` and `"` quote marks are both being passed into `sed` as `"`. I do actually need one of them there explicitly. If I only put one set into my list, then they are stripped in the command completely, which also breaks the command.

#### Things I have tried:

1. not declaring literal strings for those strings where I need explicit quotations
2. escaping and double-escaping explicit quotations
3. passing the entire command as one list into the `subprocess.Popen` and `subprocess.run` functions.
4. playing around with the [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) package to deal with quotations
5. removing the parts `cmd3_pass_output = ['>']` and `cmd3_outfile= [output_file_abs]` so that only the raw (piped) output is dealt with.

Am I missing something, or am I going to be forced to use `shell=True`?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program appears to do what you want. Each of the processes must be run separately. As you build them, the output from one gets piped out to the input of the next. The files are handled independently and used at the beginning and ending of the process.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess


def main():
    with open('raw.txt', 'r') as stdin, open('clean.txt', 'w') as stdout:
        step_1 = subprocess.Popen(
            ('tr', '-c', '[:alpha:]', ' '),
            stdin=stdin,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE
        )
        step_2 = subprocess.Popen(
            ('sed', '-E', 's/ +/ /g'),
            stdin=step_1.stdout,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE
        )
        step_3 = subprocess.Popen(
            ('tr', '[:upper:]', '[:lower:]'),
            stdin=step_2.stdout,
            stdout=stdout
        )
        step_3.wait()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Worked like a charm - very clever idea to take the files out of the equation, making it all more pythonic. If there are any drawbacks to this approach, I haven't noticed them. Does the `step_3.wait()` simply allow the file to be written before closing the process?

Comment: Yes, the call to `wait` is there to let `tr` finish what it is doing before the files are closed.